# SP Online - Get items from list(CAML) with JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, caml

I want to get list item with caml query for SharePoint Hosted Add'in.

Query will returned one item..
**This is my code:**

```
function getUserData() {
    var employeeList = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('Служители');
    var userTitle = user.get_title();
    var collListItem;
    var oListItem;

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
                          "<View><Query>" +
                          "<Where>" +
                                  "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + userTitle + "</Value></Eq>" +
                          "</Where>" +
                          "</Query></View>");
    collListItem = employeeList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title, empNickName, empPosition, empDepartment)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
    );

    function successHandler() {
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        userDepartment.innerHTML = oListItem.get_item('empNickName');
    }

    function errorHandler() {
        userDepartment.innerHTML = "Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message();
    }
}
```

Where i'm wrong ? Thank you previously!

Comment: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx) compare `onQuerySucceeded` with yours - you missed `listItemEnumerator.moveNext()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put while loop for `listItemEnumerator`.

Try below code:

```
function getUserData() {
    var employeeList = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('Служители');
    var userTitle = user.get_title();
    var collListItem;
    var oListItem;

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
                          "<View><Query>" +
                          "<Where>" +
                                  "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + userTitle + "</Value></Eq>" +
                          "</Where>" +
                          "</Query></View>");
    collListItem = employeeList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title, empNickName, empPosition, empDepartment)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
    );

    function successHandler() {
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {    
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        alert(oListItem.get_item('empNickName'));
        }
        //userDepartment.innerHTML = oListItem.get_item('empNickName');
    }

    function errorHandler() {
        userDepartment.innerHTML = "Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message();
    }
}
```

It will give you alert for all your items.

Thanks @Kai.

**Reference:**

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Hope this will help you!